# Delete data older than 1 month SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to delete records from a table that are older than 1 month with
a trigger. Is that possible?

My problem consists in deleting records of a shopping cart when they are inactive for 1 month.

Comment: Please, post your table structure. Do your table has some kind of "creation_date" column?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7cbb025365718bdadbb59de5342e21ad

If Estado like 'Em Execução' for 1 month e should delete the record

Comment: @EduardoCorreia, typically, one would schedule a daily batch process with the needed SQL statement rather than use a trigger. Something like `DELETE dbo.ShoppingCart WHERE LastActivityDate < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE());`. You can use SQL Server Agent or Windows Task Scheduler to run the daily task.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
        ON database1.dbo.table1
        FOR DELETE
    AS
        DELETE FROM database1.dbo.table1
        WHERE date < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
    GO
```